# Minecraft forge doesn't load item texture 1.10.2

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to add a texture to an item I have, and it's not loading in Minecraft. Here's my base mod class:
package com.gandiber.thegalaxymod;

```
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.RenderItem;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.Item.ToolMaterial;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemSword;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.Side;
import net.minecraftforge.common.util.EnumHelper;

@Mod(modid = TheGalaxyMod.MODID, version = TheGalaxyMod.VERSION)
public class TheGalaxyMod {
    public static final String MODID = "gandiber_thegalaxymod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";
    public static ItemSword GalaxiumSword;
    public static ToolMaterial galaxium = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial("galaxium", 3, 4000, 15F, 38.0F, 22);

    @SidedProxy(serverSide = "com.gandiber.thegalaxymod.CommonProxy", clientSide = "com.gandiber.thegalaxymod.ClientProxy")
    public static CommonProxy proxy;

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        //Weapons
            GameRegistry.register(GalaxiumSword = new ItemGalaxySword(galaxium, "diamondswordcompressed"));

        // some example code
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Items.DIAMOND),
            "XXX",
            "XXX",
            "XXX",
            'X', Items.GOLD_INGOT);
    }
}
```

My common proxy class:

```
package com.gandiber.thegalaxymod;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public class CommonProxy {
    public void registerItemRenderer(Item item, int meta, String id) {

    }
}
```

My Client Proxy class:

```
package com.gandiber.thegalaxymod;

import net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader;

public class ClientProxy extends CommonProxy {
    @Override
    public void registerItemRenderer(Item item, int meta, String id) {
        ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(item, meta, new ModelResourceLocation(TheGalaxyMod.MODID + ":" + id, "inventory"));
    }
}
```

Here is the actual sword's item class:

```
package com.gandiber.thegalaxymod;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemSword;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import thegalaxymod.tutorial.item.ItemModelProvider;

public class ItemGalaxySword extends ItemSword implements ItemModelProvider {
private String name;
    public ItemGalaxySword(ToolMaterial material, String name ) {
        super(material);
        setUnlocalizedName(name);
        setRegistryName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerItemModel(Item item) {
        TheGalaxyMod.proxy.registerItemRenderer(this, 0, name);
    }
}
```

Here is the item's json model file:

```
{
    "parent": "item/generated",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "gandiber_thegalaxymod:items/diamondswordcompressed"
    },
  "display":{
      "thirdperson":{
          "rotation":[-90, 0, 0],
          "translation":[0, 1, -3],
          "scale":[0.55,0.55,0.55]
      },
      "firstperson":{
          "rotation":[0,-135,25],
          "translation":[0,4,2],
        "scale":[1.7,1.7,1.7]
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the rendering class thing which does basically nothing:

```
package thegalaxymod.tutorial.item;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public interface ItemModelProvider {
    void registerItemModel(Item item);
}
```

And finally here's the actual PNG:
[image]
I hope you are able to download this. If not, please tell me!

My folder structure:

Json file:
C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Mods\Auto-Bow\src\main\resources\assets\gandiber_thegalaxymod\models\item\diamondswordcompressed.json

PNG file:
C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Mods\Auto-Bow\src\main\resources\assets\gandiber_thegalaxymod\textures\items\diamondswordcompressed.json

Things I have tried:

- Removing the second part of the json file so that only "layer0" is present.
- Removing the "inventory" argument in the setCustomModelResourceLocation method.

Also if this is helpful to anybody here is my fml-client-latest.log file:
[(Pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/raw/nzwM7bWc)

Comment: What mc version is this?

Comment: It's 1.10.2, I'll add it to the title. Thanks!

Comment: Oh... Sorry man, I can only work with 1.8.9 :/ Wish I could help... :(

Comment: That's okay. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. Of course with my luck, I spent 3 hours debugging the problem, and figured out the answer within 10 minutes of asking the question.

There were two problems:

1. As BdoubleB97 said, in my "ItemGalaxySword" class, I forgot to assign the value of the parameter "name" to the global variable "name". This was the small problem.
2. The other problem was that the "registerItemModel" method was never being called. I actually made a different method in ItemGalaxySword called initmodel which accomplishes the same thing, but now I have a method in TheGalaxyMod that calls the initmodel method from all of my classes, and finally, the client proxy calls that method. This code should clear that up a bit:

EDIT: Will post code later today, ran out of time.

Comment: Ok good, you reference the ModelLoader in your client proxy. A lot of people put that call in their item class which is a no-no. However, you should be using the registry name (`getRegistryName()`) for both the unlocalized name and the item model registration. Take a look at [my registry](https://github.com/Draco18s/ReasonableRealism/blob/master/src/main/java/com/draco18s/hardlib/EasyRegistry.java) [classes](https://github.com/Draco18s/ReasonableRealism/blob/master/src/main/java/com/draco18s/hardlib/client/ClientEasyRegistry.java) (there are two links there).

Answer (score 0):

In your `ItemGalaxySword` class you never set the instance Variable `name`.
You should add `this.name = name` to the Constructor.

Comment: True, but this is only part of the problem. I have figured out the problem and will post about it in a minute.